# Can a PlyGem Alenco Window With the Sash Inside the Glass Be Switched To Glass With the Sash On the Outside?

Tags: windows, replacement, glass

I'd appreciate any advice with this issue. I just purchased a home with a detached garage that has PlyGem Alenco windows. The sash is inside the window glass. The main home has windows with an exterior sash that can be painted. We intend to paint them a dark brown color. The windows on the detached garage are going to stick out like a sore thumb since the fixed interior sash is white.

My question is this. Can I keep the existing PlyGem Alenco frame and casing intact, but replace the glass to plain glass and add exterior sashes that can be painted to match the windows of the main house?

Obviously, if the window was broken, I'm sure I could replace the glass. But I'm not sure if there is way to add the exterior sashes?

There is a gold sticker in the window that has the following specs:

CODE: A-162-1
SPEC: H-R30
SERIES: 3852
MST: 3860

[image: Window]

[image]

Comment: By "sash", do you mean the grille (the bars inside the window that "divide" it into panes)?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Have you tried contacting the manufacturer? And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.